# Websphre portal does not startup

Tags: rad, websphere-portal

When I try to start up a websphere portal server, it hangs at the line :

> Server WebSphere_Portal open for e-business

and although it means that the server started up successfully, it is not...because in the progress bar, i stll see 'Starting.....' I have tried deleting the wstemp and temp directories but beyond that I am not sure what I can do to debug the problem.

The server with the same profile starts up great from another workspace, but when I come to this workspace, it just hangs at

> Server WebSphere_Portal open for e-business

I am using RAD 7 and portal 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaushik,

Try and change the connection type between RAD and WebSphere Portal.Switch it between SOAP and RMI and see if that makes a difference.

Double click the server and in the property editor you can specify the connection method.

Check this link out

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207553

HTH

Manglu